# JQuery/JavaScript How to toggle letter 's' to list of time periods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

Is there a simple way of adding and removing a trailing letter 's' to a list of time periods?

So for example, when a user enters a value of 5 into an input, an adjacent list of 'day', 'week', 'month' and 'year' have the letter 's' appended to the end.

And if the user was to enter a value of 1, that letter 's' would be removed from the list of time periods (that is if it had already been appended by this script).

Here is what I have so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.format-input').each(function() {

    $(this).keyup(function() {

      if (parseInt($(this).val()) > 1) {

        $(this).siblings('.format').eq(0).children().each(function() {

          if ($(this).val() > 1) {

            txt = $(this).html().concat('s');
            $(this).html(txt);

          }

        });

      }

    });

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="combined-input">

  <input type="text" name="length[]" class="length format-input" />

  <select name="stay_format_id[]" class="format">
    <option value="day">day</option>
    <option value="week">week</option>
    <option value="month">month</option>
    <option value="year">year</option>
  </select>


</div>
```

The above is not a good solution. Each time a key is pressed on/in the input, the letter 's' is appended to the time periods. So what happens is when a user enters a value with more than one digit, e.g. three-digits, the letter 's' would be appended for every digit that had been entered (e.g. daysss).

It also does not address the scenario in which a user enters a number above 5, and then changes it back to a value below 2.

I thought that this might be a commonly asked/answered question because I have seen this feature in a few different apps over the years, but I haven't been able to find anything on it. Any help would be appreciated!

**James.**

Comment: The built-in INTL object might be able to help https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/PluralRules/PluralRules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am correct you want to change the value of the text within your drop down to plural if the input value is greater than 1...

In this case you can write two event handlers, one to check the change of the select, the other to check the blur of the input.

In the first event for the selection, select the child that is selected with `option:selected`, then run a conditional to see if the input is empty, if it is not empty, we check its value to see if it is greater than `1`, we set the selected options text to plural, else we leave the options text value alone.

The second event is for the `blur` of the input, so when focus leaves the input field... Check the value fo the input using `$(this)` and see if it is greater than `1`, if it is, we change the selected options text to plural by concatonating an `s` on the end of the options text...

```js
let $selection = $('.format');
let $input = $('.format-input');
// set up a function for the check
let setPlural = ($selection, $input) => {
  // event handler for the select option change
  $selection.change(function() {
    // get the child that is selected using this
    window.selected = $(this).children("option:selected");
    // this conditional will ensure the select options text stays plural if the user 
    // changes the select with an input greater than 1 still in the input field. 
    if (parseInt($input.val()) !== '') { // check that the value is not empty `!== ''`
      //check if the value is greater than 1
      if (parseInt($input.val()) > 1) {
        // pluralize the text of the option that is selected
        selected.text(selected.val() + 's');
      } else {
        selected.text(selected.val());
      }
    }
  });
  // input event handler on blur
  $input.blur(function() {
    //check if this value is greater than 1
    if (parseInt($(this).val()) > 1) {
      selected.text(selected.val() + 's');
    } else {
      selected.text(selected.val());
    }
  });
}

setPlural($selection, $input);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="combined-input">
  <input type="text" name="length[]" class="length format-input" />
  <select name="stay_format_id[]" class="format">
    <option selected disabled>Choose one</option>
    <option value="day">day</option>
    <option value="week">week</option>
    <option value="month">month</option>
    <option value="year">year</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Generally not a good practice adding an event listener inside another event handler

Comment: Change the reference variable for the select to a global using `window.selected = ` allows the two event handlers to process outside of each others scope.